# is it possible to replace ubuntu with fedora?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer. But now I want to install Fedora. Is there anyway that I can replace my Ubuntu with Fedora without loosing my installed software? My Linux is installed on one partition, I mean there isn't any other partition mounted as /usr/local or something else.

e.g. MATLAB is installed on my Ubuntu, and I do not want to bother installing it again on a new Fedora.

Comment: I think this question fits better in SuperUser...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fedora uses a different software management system then Ubuntu.

Even the linux OS itself is organized differently between the two

so the answer is no, you will need to install the software again
but that is not that hard. I'm sure you know where you stored all your personal documents etc, so back those up first

Comment: so you mean that it is only possible to replace it with some other Debian based distro?

Comment: I would say only upgrade with newer versions of the same distro is possible